# When did Obito awaken the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto Shippuden* episode 473, ...

> Kakashi uses Obito's eyes to create Susanoo. But Obito's eyes were not Eternal Mangekyou. Previously, he had Rinnegan which he has borrowed in addition to one of his own eyes, and that's why he could do lots of stuff.

When did Obito awaken the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan?

---

Note: this is not the same question as [When did Kakashi and Obito awaken their Mangekyou Sharingan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4484). Eternal Mangekyou is when someone from Uchiha gives his Mangekyou to someone dear then it becomes eternal and the powers will be activated.

Comment: You don't need the _Eternal_ MS to be able to summon Susano'o: the regular MS should be enough.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4484/49).

Comment: You need to be more specific. If you believe he had an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan, the burden of proof is on you, the OP, to justify it. The answers exist to support or refute it. Just because you claim something it what it is doesn't meant it really is that. Try to edit your question more clearly express your point, so there is less confusion on what you are trying to ask.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the answer is Obito never obtained an Eternal MS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obito never had the Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan. The user does not need the Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan to use Susanoo according to the [wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan) - just the Mangekyō Sharingan in both eyes. Once Kakashi gains the power of both of Obito's eyes, it allows him to use Susanoo. Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan increases the power of their abilities and causes the user no negative side effects such as losing vision and bleeding from the eye.

The full body Susano'o is the most powerful form granted by the Mangekyo Sharingan. Kakashi said in episode 437 at 12:53 "Gaining the Six Path's power enhances one's Visual Prowess too". It's most likely that Kakashi was able to use the full body Susano'o since when he gained the pair of his (actually Obito's) Sharingan, he also gained some of the Six Path's power Obito posessed.

Comment: How is that the case? Itachi has susanoo, but it wasn't complete since hi lack eternal mangekyou. Sasuke gained a complete susanoo right after he had his brothers eyes.

Comment: And of course it wasn't because of kakashies intelligence, because Itachi was the most talented person in the history of Konoha and after 10 years, he couldn't activate it when kakashi did in 1 sec

Comment: The full body Susanoo is the most powerful form granted by the Magekyo Sharigan. Kakashi said in episode 437 at 12:53 "Gaining the Six Path's power enhances one's Visual Prowess too". Its most likley that Kakashi was able to use the full body for because along with Obitos Sharigan he also gained some that power as well.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't need Eternal Mangekyo for the Susanoo, and if you're asking why he got the perfect Susanoo, it's because before dying, Obito had stolen some of the Six Paths Chakra from Madara, and as it was said that the Six Paths Chakra enhances and doujutsu or anything. That is the reason he was able to skip the imperfect Susanoo and the cage's to the perfect Susanoo.

Answer (score 0):

Itachi had a disease. We never got to see how strong he really was. Itachi's chakra control was so amazing that we couldn't notice he was sick. Sasuke didn't kill him, he died from the disease. That's why he needed Obito to kill the Uchiha.

Itachi was the most interesting character to me because he planned his life out and was known as one of the strongest shinobis with the sickness. That's why Itachi wasn't able to summon a perfect Susano because he was very sick and was on verge of dying.